# VMware server issues with page file and dynamic memory

Tags: performance, vmware, operating-systems, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm having significant issues on our dev server and since our systems support won't maintain it I'm trying to determine our issues. Right now we have 2 GB of memory, allocated dynamically by VMware (up to 8 GB - not sure what else is running on the VM hardware system). In running a performance report, the primary issue was high memory levels (~90% at our 2 GB mark) and what I assume is severe disc IO (1.6 queue mean, mean 10% idle time).
Our page file is set to 12 GB. Could the OS be pushing processes into page instead of gaining more memory from the VM? Is this reasonable or is there something else probably happening?

Comment: Are the page file and the vmdk files on the same physical disk?

Comment: I'm not sure... the page file is on the C:\ drive along with everything else in the OS.